# Is it possible to publish your flutter app template to pub.dev

Tags: flutter, dart

I wonder if i can publish my own flutter app template and make people use it like
`flutter create example_app --template=barans_template`

I see some packages do the `pub global activate .....` thing, I thought maybe I can do it similar to this way but I have no idea.

Comment: It's not currently supported, but it's on the radar: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15279, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/77104